# How to save specific LayerSet in photoshop using extendedScript

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have two LayerSets (artboards). One is called `thumb` second is called `big`.
When I click on Artboard i can export it via "Quick export as PNG".

How can I export specific layerSet/artBoard in extendedScript?

Comment: Quick Export isn't scriptable, you'll have to write a custom exporter. For exporting all Artboard just use Export > Artboards to Files

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thank you. But It would require me save a lot manually. Both artboards are generated dynamically through script. Will just split file into 2 PSDs